# how to view data from different tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 4 tables : `tbl_info, tbl_owner, tbl_accounts, tbl_billing`

```
--tbl_info: information
info_id | fname | lname
10      | ron   | lum

--tbl_owner: owner
own_id | owner_info_id |property_type
   01  |  10           | land 

--tbl_all_property: landfindings
property_id | property_owner_id | owner_id | OR_no  
1           | 101               | 10       | 987    
2           | 101               | 10       | 874    
3           | 101               | 10       | 875    

--tbl_billing: billing
bill_id | status   | total | property_id 
1       | not paid | 100   | 1
```

my question is how to view the value of `"fname,lname,status,total"` when I enter `ORNo = '875'`
since the `3 OR_no` was owned by the same owner.

Comment: for what purpose, why I should use create view sir?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select a.fname,
       a.lname,
       d.status,
       d.total 
from tbl_info a 
inner join tbl_owner b 
      on a.info_id=b.owner_info_id 
inner join tbl_all_property c 
     on c.owner_id=b.owner_info_id 
inner join tbl_billing d 
     on d.property_id=c.property_id 
where c.OR_no='875'
```

Comment: sir, the query will give no results when i execute in postgres

Comment: its ok sir JumboClip, and tnx also for the idea.